# setInterval or window.location are not working properly with Opera, IE and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, cookies, setinterval

I'm trying to make a redirection if a cookie exist, it's working on Chrome and Firefox, but it's not on Opera, IE and Safari.

```
function listenCookieChange() {
   var intervalHolder = setInterval(function() {
   if(getCookie('foo')){
      clearInterval(intervalHolder);

      window.location.href = 'http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/inscription2.php';
   }
}, 100);
}
listenCookieChange();
```

The cookies are set on the browser so the problem is not coming from that part.

Thanks in advance

Edit: Here's the code for the getCookie

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x==c_name)
        {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code you have for getCookie()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can not find any fault. Have tested your script on IE7-IE9 and Opera 10-11.

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

function listenCookieChange() {
    var intervalHolder = setInterval(function() {
        if (getCookie('foo')) {
            clearInterval(intervalHolder);

            //window.location.href = 'http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/inscription2.php';
            alert('true');
        }
    }, 100);
}
listenCookieChange();

document.cookie = 'foo = true';​
```

Comment: It seem like the problem only happen with PHP cookies. I will look more into it. Thanks your answer helped me.